# Delete object in foreach

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I got an exception which said:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager

when I call `DeleteObject()` in a `ForEach` loop. After I searched this question in google, I failed to find the answer yet, and I didn't found anything wrong with my code, below.

There exists one to many relationship between `DHEntity` and `DHEntityVersion`.

```
public IList<DHEntity> GetAllDHEntity(Guid packId)
{
    using (DiaDataContext db = new DiaDataContext(ConnectionStrings.LogDB))
    {
        var subPackList = new List<DHEntity>();
        subPackList = db.DHEntities.Include(d=>d.DHEntityVersions).Where(p => p.PackageId == packId).ToList();
        return subPackList;
    }
}

private void Delete()
{
    using (DiaDataContext db = new DiaDataContext(ConnectionStrings.LogDB))
    {
        var subPacks = GetAllDHEntity(packId);////This method used another context. maybe it is the reason cause the problem .
        foreach (var subpack in subPacks)
        {
            var vList = db.DHEntityVersions.Where(v =>v.DHEntityId == subpack.ID).ToList();
            foreach (var version in vList)
            {
                db.DeleteObject(version);
            }
            db.DeleteObject(subpack);//the debugger stop here along with the exception I mentioned before.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the object is from another Data Context.

The Context `GetAllDHEntity` used to fetch the item is not the one to `Delete` it, which is why that object's state doesn't exist.